# Transformation using triangular weighting function in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, math, transformation

I trying to built a hydrological model and according to the model, i need to transform  my QGW variable using the below formula:

[image: |triangular transformation function]

where: QGW = is a list and MAXBIAS = constant (usually 5).

I really don't know where to start... to built it using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

A few caveats to this answer. I am neither a Python or Hydrological model expert. The following is a start, **not** a final answer. You can therefore fix any problems from this starting point.

```python
class HydroModel:
  def __init__(self, maxbias, qcw):
    self.maxbias = maxbias
    self.qcw = qcw

  def Fu(u): 
    # antiderivative
    # needs fixing because antiderivatives of absolute values have to be split
    maxbias = self.maxbias
    return u*2/maxbias - u * math.fabs(u - maxbias/2) * 4 / (maxbias*maxbias)

  def c(i): 
    return Fu(i-1)-Fu(i)

  def Qsim(t):
    # is this meant to return a value or a list/vector?
    sum = 0
    for (i = 1; i < self.maxbias; i++):
        sum += self.c(i) * self.qcw[ t - i + 1]
    return sum
```